# Getting sum by comparing two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays, one that contains a list of products, and the other is an orders arrays that contains the orderinfo of multiple purchases.

For example, the products array would look like this:

```
const products = [
    {price: 10, id: 123, ...}
     ,
    ...
 ]
```

and the orders array would look like:

```
const orders = [
   
   {
     shippinginfo: {...},
     orderinfo: {
        note: 'a message for the seller',
        paymentType: 'visa',
        products: [
          {
           id: 123,
           qty: 5
          }
         ]
      }
   }

 ]
```

So my question is, how exactly can i go about summing the price of all the orders in this orders array?

Comment: Is the price inside the products array, which in turn is inside the orders array?

Comment: Offhand looping through products, finding the ID in the products array, then do your  math. That said, unless this is just a learning exercise, I believe you may lose the actual price for the order this way if a price for a product ever changes. Might be worth exploring keeping the unit price on the product object within the order. Has the added benefit of simplifying the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through works  ! To create it more usable added some random products ... It will give you sum of the all products in array of orders

```
  const orders = [{
    orderinfo: {
      note: 'a message for the seller',
      paymentType: 'visa',
      products: [{
        id: 123,
        qty: 5
      },
  
        {
          id: 13,
          qty: 2
        }]
    }
  }]
  const products = [{
    price: 10,
    id: 123
  },
    {
      price: 100,
      id: 13
    },
  
  ]
  
  let sum = 0;
  
  orders.forEach(order => {
    order.orderinfo.products.forEach(item => {
      products.forEach(product => {
        if (item.id === product.id) {
          sum += product.price * item.qty
        }
      })
    })
  });
  
  console.log(sum)
```

Comment: @User123123 Does this answer solves your problem ?

Comment: Would it also be possible to display a new array of all products based on which item was sold the most?

Comment: @User123123 Not getting it an example might work

Comment: sorting the products array based on which item has been sold the most, so if  item id=13 was sold 100 times and item id=123 was sold 30 times, then sort the array in descending order

Comment: @User123123 Yep it can be done but first you need a backend to store the count of the sold item (every time person makes an order )  and then pass the count with in the products object .. After this using js and little logic it can be achieved

Comment: @User123123 you can open a sperate thread to deal with this I am sure you will find something good !

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this:

```js
const products = [{
  price: 10,
  id: 123
}]
const orders = [{
  shippinginfo: "",
  orderinfo: {
    note: 'a message for the seller',
    paymentType: 'visa',
    products: [{
      id: 123,
      qty: 5
    }]
  }
}];


let obj = {};
products.forEach((product) => {
  obj[product.id] = product;
});

orders.forEach((order) => {
  order.orderinfo.products.forEach((product) => {
    product.price = obj[product.id].price * product.qty;
  });
});

console.log(orders);
```

Comment: Creating an hash table was the way to go

Answer (score -1):

You can Do it Like This:

```js
const products = [
    {price: 10, id: 123}
]
const orders = [
   {
     shippinginfo: "",
     orderinfo: {
        note: 'a message for the seller',
        paymentType: 'visa',
        products: [
          {
           id: 123,
           qty: 5
          }
         ]
      }
   }
]


var sum = 0
for (let i = 0;i<orders.length;i++){
  var order = orders[i]
  var orderinfo = order["orderinfo"]
  var products1 = orderinfo["products"]
  for (let j = 0;j<products1.length;j++){
    var product1 = products1[j]
    for (let k = 0;k<products.length;k++){
      if (products[k]["id"] == product1["id"]){
        sum += products[k]["price"]*product1["qty"]
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(sum); // 50
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const orders = [{
    orderinfo: {
        note: 'a message for the seller',
        paymentType: 'visa',
        products: [{
            id: 123,
            qty: 5
        },

        {
            id: 13,
            qty: 2
        }]
    }
}]
const products = [{
    price: 10,
    id: 123
},
{
    price: 100,
    id: 13
},

]
// finds price of order's product and  multiply by qty
let sumOfOrders = orders.orderinfo.products.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (products.find(f => f.id === cur.id)).price * cur.qty)
```